# Manually installed jar in local repository cannot be seen by m2e

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin

I use M2E maven plugin for Eclipse and have maven instaled separately. 
I installed Oracle driver:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=D:\apps\ojdbc.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

...

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but m2e cannot see the jar

Form Window->Preferences->Maven->UserSettings I set the plugin to point to the same setting.xml as the other Maven so both look at C:\Users\myUser.m2\repository (I think...)
Actually I can't find `ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar` in the repo, but there is`ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar.lastUpdated`
Maybe something with the file install went wrong, but the log says it's OK.

Comment: What is exactly the message? Also, if you use both command line and m2eclipse, it's better to make Eclipse use your external installation (Maven -> Installations).

Comment: Just delete the 11.2.0 folder under maven repository then run the command again and see if it is installed properly, as long as your have ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar there (actually you can directly copy jar there and delete *.lastUpdated in 11.2.0), you should be fine.

Comment: It was wrong path to the jar ojdbc.jar instead of ojdbc6.jar. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are seeing is a .lastUpdated then your mvn install did not work correctly.

EDIT:

Try specifying -Dgeneratepom=true as another parameter along with all of the others you have specified.